# Please some one explain spring -security integration with CAS.I am not able to understand

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to integrate CAS authentication with spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817928/how-to-integrate-cas-authentication-with-spring-security)

here is my problem.. [How to integrate CAS authentication with spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817928/how-to-integrate-cas-authentication-with-spring-security)

I have gone through following link 
http://code.google.com/p/dsn-chassis/wiki/SpringCasIntegration
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html

But not able to make things work..

I have separate spring-context.xml file and spring-security.xml file. I am not able to add following codes

```
   <bean id="serviceProperties"
            class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service"
            value="https://localhost:8443/cas-sample/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
      </bean>
```

into my spring-security.xml as getting name space error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
```

Moreover what is the use of the above code? I have one service which I was using to perform authentication ,now how can I check that if CAS is authenticated then proceed to my application else ask user to authenticate CAS.
I hope shome one will show me correct path.If someone can let me know step by step process then it will be really good